# Django, not seeing request.path. Am using RequestContext

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to get request.path in my template but I get nothing. Everything else on the page works fine. I have done:

In views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext

return render_to_response('frontpage.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my template frontpage.html

```
{{ request.path  }}
```

What else am I missing? I'd post some code, but I don't know were to begin.

Edit: Am using localhost in case that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#template-context-processors)
setting includes [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request); that's what actually adds the `request` variable. This isn't on by default.

(Also, [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) is usually easier than `render_to_response` with an explicit `RequestContext`.)

Comment: Worked perfectly. I didn't even have a TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_SETTING. Thought I kept everything standard. Thanks.